# How to Adding multiple element using JS push()?

Tags: javascript

I can't push html data with multiple element using Javascript, I want the html output like this :

```
    <li class="swipeout">
      <label class="label-checkbox item-content swipeout-content">
        <input type="checkbox" name="ks-checkbox" value="Books" />
        <div class="item-media"><i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i></div>
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">Lifebuoy Soap</div>
          <div class="item-after">6.000</div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" data-confirm="Are you sure want to delete this?" class="swipeout-delete">Delete</a></div>
    </li>
```

I've try in https://jsfiddle.net/ferdyzz4/ee7c7ca9/ , but the output isn't same. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to need to expand on what you are trying to do a lot.  Your question is very confusing.

Comment: I wan't to push html data using javascript, and the output should be like above.

Comment: So you want to actually write to your html file from the javascript running within it?

Comment: yes, exactly @Guest01

Comment: An `<input>` element is an empty element and should not have an element as a child at HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't append the div to your input, just append the input to label as you were before:

```
    label.appendChild(input)
```

This would give you the desired result based on your code from the fiddle:

```
  addAnother = function() {
      var ul = document.getElementById("list");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      var i = document.createElement("i");
      var itemInner = document.createElement("div");
      var itemTitle = document.createElement("div");
      var itemAfter = document.createElement("div");
      var swipeOut = document.createElement("div");
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      var children = ul.children.length + 1
      li.setAttribute("class", "swipeout")
       label.setAttribute("class", "label-checkbox item-content swipeout-content")
       input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox")
       input.setAttribute("name", "ks-checkbox")
       input.setAttribute("value", "Test")
      label.appendChild(input)
      div.setAttribute("class", "item-media")
      i.setAttribute("class", "icon icon-form-checkbox")
      div.appendChild(i)
      label.appendChild(div)
      li.appendChild(label)
      itemInner.setAttribute("class", "item-inner")
      itemTitle.setAttribute("class", "item-title")
      itemTitle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element "+children));
      itemAfter.setAttribute("class", "item-after")
      itemInner.appendChild(itemTitle)
      itemInner.appendChild(itemAfter)
      li.appendChild( itemInner )
      swipeOut.setAttribute("class", "swipeout-actions-right")
      link.setAttribute("class", "swipeout-delete");
      link.setAttribute("href", "#")
      link.setAttribute("data-confirm", "Are you sure want to delete this?" )
      swipeOut.appendChild(link);
      li.appendChild(swipeOut);

      ul.appendChild(li)
  }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L3Lqupbr/4/

Comment: You're perfect, thanks @tim-elsass